# Multiple assignment in XML schema

Tags: xml, syntax, relaxng

Is there any way to write a markup like following in Relax NG compact (It seems that it have not a counterpart in Relax NG XML)

```
bar = foo =  element title {text}
```

In future somebody may want assign different value to bar and foo, but until that time he wants to use above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
bar = foo
foo = element title {text}
```

See also the entry [Named Patterns](http://relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html#id2814516) in the RELAX NG Compact Syntax Tutorial, which discusses this exact syntax:

```
start = e
e = element element { text }
```